# CSS Font Mysterious (4me) Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I've a CSS question. I'm using Rails 3.0 and trying to design a site of mine. I found this anoying problem previously also but now is the time to find a solution.

The situation: I set up a CSS like this:

```
*               {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
body            {background-color: #1d1122; font:12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif #fff; width: 100%;}
a               {color: blue; outline: none; text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover         {text-decoration: none;}
p               {margin: 0 0 18px}
img             {border: none;}
input           {vertical-align: middle;}
#wrapper        {width: 955px; margin: 0 auto;}

/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header         {background: transparent url(../images/header.jpg) no-repeat; height: 413px;}
#navigation     {background: transparent url(../images/menu_bg.jpg) no-repeat; height:36px;}

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#middle         {width: 100%; height: 1%; position: relative;}
#middle:after   {content: '.'; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; height: 0;}
#container      {background: transparent url(../images/main_bg.jpg) no-repeat; width: 100%; float: left; overflow: hidden;}
#content        {padding: 0 270px 0 0;}

/* Sidebar Right
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#sideRight      {float: left; margin-right: -3px; width: 313px; margin-left: -313px; position: relative;}

/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer         {background: transparent url(../images/footer.jpg) no-repeat; height: 63px;}

/*Content
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#prediction_box {width:290px; height:200px; position:relative; background-color:#392b3f; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 25px 25px 40px 40px;}
```

When I start to write something on my index page, this wont be 12px Arial as I set in the body tag. The wierness starts if I wan't to have the text in white.

```
body            {font-color:#fff; background-color: #1d1122; font:12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif #fff; width: 100%;}
```

If I use the font-color:#fff; than nothing happens. However if I use font: #fff 12px/18px etc... than suddenly the texts will be Arial 12px but still in black!

Can you explain how is this possible?

Looking forward your answears,

Kael

Comment: The correct property is color, not font-color.

Comment: there might be another css file that override the style. Use firebug or developer tools in your browser to see the final assigned style. You can also see from which file it comes from

Comment: Just as a general FYI, the shortened `font` styling can sometimes be finicky and not like to work properly. If you're having trouble with the font working, it can be useful to expand your font styles out to the individual properties for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS does not define a `font-color` property. You'll need to use the `color` property as so: `color: #fff;` in order for the foreground colour (font colour) to become white.

Comment: To put it another way, there is no CSS property called `font-color`; instead the property that affects the foreground color of a font is called `color`.

Comment: Its done. Thank you. This is allways the same. I dont know something.